# Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap. I do provide a bitmap

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

Currently, I am working on an app that uses the Google Maps API to plot points on the map where the user takes pictures. These images are stored and retrieved from a database that I create. When the map first starts up, I retrieve the pictures and plot the points. After getting the byte[] from the database, I convert it to a bitmap and set the marker icon to be that bitmap inside a DescriptorFactory. However, the compiler throws an error about how the provided image must be a bitmap. I am 99% sure it is.

```
private void plotMarkers(GoogleMap mMap) {

    ImageHelper imageHelper = new ImageHelper(this, null, null, 1);
    markers = imageHelper.selectAll();
    if(markers.size() > 0)
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (imageHelper.getImage(index));
            MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(myMarker.getLatitude(), myMarker.getLongitude()))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));


            Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);

            markersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap)`

Also please specify type of your global variables next time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I'll be sure to do that next time. It turns out that I had the right method calls and all, but my index started at zero, when in fact SQLite starts at 1. It's a learning process!